# Unzipping Zip files in ruby efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to validate zip files in a rails application. I am able to unzip a large file and read from it, however, all I want is to validate the first line of the file without completely loading it into memory. Below is my code for unzipping the file and validating the headers in a CSV.

```
require 'zip'
require 'csv'
decompressed_file = Zip::File.open('my_file.csv.zip').entries[0].get_input_stream.read
headers = CSV.new(decompressed_zip).read.shift
```

Again, this takes a while for larger files because it loaded it into memory. I am looking for a more elegant solution that I could just come out with the first line without having to unzip the entire file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's specifically a single file and doesn't contain a directory structure, you can probably use Zlib/gunzip for this; recommend googling around for something like "rails extract partial header data from zip", but here is a docs reference for Zlib: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib.html#gunzip-method

Comment: In this case it's probably a better idea to just follow what Allison said and check the header data, but if you find yourself trying to open large files you can defer that to a job by using Active Job.